# apache Solr-4.0.0 Unable to load mysql Driver with Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to integrate apache Sonr(apache-solr-4.0.0) with Tomcat and getting below error.

```
15:12:40    SEVERE  DataImporter    Delta Import Failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: 
Could not load driver:  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:273)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class ' com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:436)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:889)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried below option’s of adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar, but none worked

1. added as part of war (solr.war/WEB-INF/lib )
2. added as part of web server (Tomcat/lib)
3. Created a new directory lib under example/solr and placed the mysql connector jar (mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar) and refered the lib path  from solr.xml.

Any help highly appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trailing space in the name of the class:

```
Error loading class '*** ***com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

Remove the trailing spaces.

HIH